# DriverManager.getConnection Dinámicamente

Tags: java, mariadb, jar, localhost

Estoy realizando una aplicación Java, y tengo la siguiente clase conexión:

```
String direccion = "localhost:3306";
String database = "basedatos";
String usuario = "root";
String paswword = "";

public Connection ConectarMariaDB() //El codigo es más largo, pero es solo para mostrar la duda
{
    Class.forName("org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver");
       this.conectar = 
    DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mariadb://"+direccion+"/"+database, usuario, paswword);
}
```

Conecté de manera local varias pc's cambiando la variable "direccion" en el Netbeans, pero al crear el JAR, no puedo cambiar la variable para que se conecte, ni tampoco puedo almacenarlo en la base de datos, ya que no se va a conectar, ni quisiera que el usuario cada vez que se conecte tenga que escribir la dirección.

¿hay una manera de cambiar la variable dinámicamente y almacenarla? ¿O hay otra manera de conectar más óptima de manera local a la BD?

De antemano, muchas gracias.

Comment: No se entiende bien tu pregunta ni tampoco el sentido de la misma. ¿Por qué cambia el puerto del `localhost`? ¿Cómo vas a saber qué puerto es cada vez? Lo correcto sería que la BD corra siempre en el mismo puerto. En cuanto a guardar sí, lo puedes hacer, por ejemplo en un archivo de texto... lo que no entiendo es para qué o cómo vas a decidir según el equipo del cual te conectes qué puerto se debe usar... ni por qué tiene que cambiar el puerto cada vez.

Comment: No el puerto, ahi si fue mal planteamiento, sino el localhost. En vez del localhost, sería a la dirección de la pc que esta como servidor. El puerto, obviamente se queda abierto, para la comunicación entre las pc's. Ahora, si sé que se puede guardar en un archivo de texto, pero siento, no sé si esta mal, que poner una dirección de conexión en un archivo de texto es inseguro.